# Reference seemingly not working, no apparent error thrown

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dll

I have superficial knowledge on referencing libraries in projects. Usually most of the time a simple 'add reference' and then browsing to the appropriate path, just works. I am following an issue I will try to explain , and show all the approaches I tried to tackle it.

[image]

I am trying to use AutoIt. In their website it is stated that simply adding the .dll and using it, is enough to integrate their functionality in visual studio.

I am doing just that but for the moment I can not get my head around what is happening.

AutoItX is a public static class, as also the Run function is the same (public static). After adding the reference I can navigate to the appropriate .cs (if I control click on it for example). So the class AutoItX is not something unknown for the project. Moreover, the function Run indeed exists

[image]

however not inside the project itself. AutoItX also needs staff from (dont know if it is important):
[image]

The main error is that AutoItX doesnt exist in this context.

I have tried to register the dll, I have tried to add the com reference and remove it, I have tried to move the .cs files inside the project. None of those corrected the issue.

Any help would be valuable. If I missed something and you need extra info, I am willing to provide it. (Latest vs, latest autoit version, .net framework type of project).

Comment: If you build your project, do you get an error emssage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I installed AutoItX.Dotnet 3.3.14.5, my test is no problem.
You can refer to my steps to create a new project to test it.

Right click  References=>Manage NuGet Packages=>Browse=>AutoItX.Dotnet=>Install

[image: here]

Running result:

[image: here]

Answer (score 2):

Actually the above works.

For future reference.

The reason I did not try it first was, that they propose in their website to reference the autoItX.assembly.dll. This is probably deprecated and does NOT work anymore.

Second, if you have already referenced it , downloading this from NuGet WONT fix it.

Finally, the NuGet package does NOT work with .net CORE but ONLY with .net Framework project